# error: unhashable type: 'list'. While using df.groupby.apply

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Here's my dataframe:

[image]

I want to sort my dataframe by *`airline`* and then within this group by *`tweet_created`*. *`airline`* and *`tweet_created`* are two columns in my dataframe. I tried te following

```
df.groupby(['airline']).apply(lambda x: x.sort_values(['tweet_created'])).reset_index(drop = True)
```

But got this error:

```
unhashable type: 'list'
```

I don't understand what's going wrong here. Can someone help me?

Comment: Hi @Justin.  We typically want to see a [mcve] in order to see what is going on.  However, I'm willing to guess that the elements of your `'tweet_created'` column are lists and therefore cannot be sorted.

Comment: Hey Justin! Could you add some example of your data? Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for guidance on how to properly post examples

Comment: It looks like you can just sort your df, eg: `df.sort_values(['airline', 'tweet_created'])` and there's no need for a groupby?

Comment: @piRSquared, If i only sort by 'tweet_created' it works

Comment: @JonClements Thats is also not working

Comment: @Justin this is why we want a [mcve] to avoid confusion and us guessing what is going on.  You can solve this problem by taking the time to present a complete picture of what you are trying to do.

Comment: Your example data (which'd be much better as a code block as an [edit] to your question than an image) shows your airline column contains lists - so a groupby on them won't work, but a sort definitely does... so you'll need to elaborate on what you mean by *Thats is also not working*...

Comment: @Justin, Does the below solution solve your problem? If it does, consider [accepting it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer), otherwise feel free to ask for clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your sample dataframe, it appears your `airline` series consists of `list` objects. Since `list` is mutable and not hashable, it can't be used for grouping operations. Internally, `GroupBy` relies on hashing.

Assuming each list within your `airline` series consists of only one element, you can transform your data before grouping. One way is via `itertools.chain`.

```
from itertools import chain

df = pd.DataFrame({'airline': [['VirginAmerica'], ['united'], ['USAirways']]})

df['airline'] = list(chain.from_iterable(df['airline']))

print(df)

         airline
0  VirginAmerica
1         united
2      USAirways
```

Some performance benchmarking of alternative methods:

```
# pandas v0.19.2, python 3.6.0

df = pd.concat([df]*1000, ignore_index=True)

%timeit list(chain.from_iterable(df['airline']))  # 228 µs per loop
%timeit np.concatenate(df['airline'])             # 84.9 ms per loop
%timeit df['airline'].apply(pd.Series)            # 817 ms per loop
```

Comment: How do those approaches compare to `df.airline.apply(pd.Series)` ?

Comment: It's **massively** expensive...  1.09 ms ± 59.1 µs per loop vs 
77.7 µs ± 1.59 µs per loop - ouch! I'd have expected a bit more lifting going on for that but not quite as much as that...

Comment: Yeh, so `itertools` seems to win here.